# Angular 7 ng-select getting items from a function, repeated infinite times

Tags: angular

I need to assign workers to jobs and I should only be able to select workers, that have specific competences that the job requires.

Functions themselves work fine, but due to the infinite loop it freezes my site.

Markup:

```
<div *ngIf="objectServiceForm.value.service != null">
      <h5 *ngIf="objectServiceForm.value.service != null" class="font-weight-bold mt-4">Tööd</h5>
      <div formArrayName="objectServiceJobs"
           *ngFor="let item of objectServiceForm.controls['objectServiceJobs'].controls; let i = index">
        <div class="form-row mt-2 p-2" style="background: #f9f9f9;" [formGroupName]="i" >
          <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
            <h6>{{item?.controls.job.value.name}}</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <ng-select formControlName="workDetail" class="custom" [items]="getCompetentWorkers(item?.controls.job)"  [multiple]="false" [closeOnSelect]="true"
                       [searchable]="true" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Vali vaikimisi operaator">
            </ng-select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is with ng-select [items] functionality, heres the function:

```
getCompetentWorkers(job) {
    if (job.value.competences.length > 0) {
      const competentWorkers = [];
      this.workers.forEach(worker => {
        if (this.arrayContainsAnotherArray(job.value.competences.map(e => e.id), worker.competences.map(e => e.id))) {
          competentWorkers.push(worker);
        }
      });
      return competentWorkers;
    } else {
      return this.workers;
    }
  }

  arrayContainsAnotherArray(needle, haystack) {
    for (let i = 0; i < needle.length; i++) {
      if (haystack.indexOf(needle[i]) === -1) {
        console.log(haystack.indexOf(needle[i]) === -1);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

The console.log in arrayContainsAnotherArray() get repeated infinately and it makes the modal I'm using this in, unusable.

Is there anyway to check for workers once instead of all the time?

Answer (score 1):

To better once loop read items at `*ngFor` angular lifecycle moved to `ngOnInit()` function.

like ...

```
ngOnInit(){
    for(let item of objectServiceForm.controls['objectServiceJobs'].controls){
        item.workers = this.getCompetentWorkers(item.controls.job)
    }
}
```